# Re-attach event to newly loaded div

Tags: jquery, events

Apparently my JQuery events die when the elements are replaced. Currently they are attached like this:

```
$("a[id^='anb']").click(
        function () {
            /* ommited for readability */;
            var furl = "target_view";
            $('#my_article_container').load(furl, function() {
                       animateThem(); });
            return false;
        }

    );

    $("div[id^='art']").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
        }
    );
```

Is there a mechanisme inside JQuery or a handy work around on how to re-bind these events?

Comment: the animateThem() function is called as a call-back here, to animate the elements after they are loaded succesfully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the `.live()` [function](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

This will monitor the dom and reattach events automatically as items are added.

```
$("a[id^='anb']").live('click',
    function () {
        /* ommited for readability */;
        var furl = "target_view";
        $('#my_article_container').load(furl, function() {
                   animateThem(); });
        return false;
    }

);

$("div[id^='art']").live('hover',
    function() {
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    }
);
```

Comment: @Drackir: it seems that my click event dies, yet my hover event works partially. :(

Comment: @Shyam - is it throwing any errors? I don't think `.live()` accepts two callbacks for the `hover` event which is probably why it's only partially working.

Comment: Nope, but I discovered there are more things in my scripts to addify with .live(), yet the hover thingie doesn't hover out. Is there a workaround for hover?

Comment: .live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) { (event.type == 'mouseover') { /* ... */ } else { /* ... */ }}); < this works :)

Comment: This answer is outdated. `.live` has been removed from jQuery for a long time. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25856395/1000608) is the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

This was the first answer that came up when I googled it - me having the same problem. Live has been deprecated in version 1.7 and removed in version 1.9. The new versions of JQuery recommend using on. [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Anyway, just to keep this up to date. I the end I got mine to work by **including the selector** in the on function eg:

```
$(document).on("click","a[id^='anb']",function(){....})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use $.live() instead, which is designed to work for this very case.

```
$("a[id^='anb']").live('click', function() { ... });
$("a[id^='art']").live('hover', function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

[Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is your friend

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)